# Если больше 3 элементов div, перемещать их в другой контейнер

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Имеется множество div с одинаковым классом `dashboard__dropdown-item` , в примере их 6. На деле может быть меньше или больше. Необходимо чтобы если их больше 3 добавлять их в родитель с классом `dashboard__dropdown-container`, а также добавлять им класс `dashboard__dropdown-item-active`. При этом первые 3 div оставлять в том же месте.

Класс я добавляю, но из-за того что это делается динамически я не могу добавить их в родитель `dashboard__dropdown-container`

Подскажите как это можно сделать? Всем заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

```js
    $('.dashboard__dropdown-item').addClass( firstThreeOnly );
    function firstThreeOnly( index, classAttribute ) {
        return ( index > 2 ? 'dashboard__dropdown-item-active' : '' );
        $('.dashboard__dropdown-item-active').appendTo('.dashboard__dropdown-container');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard__items-content">
    <a href="#" class="dashboard__dropdown-item">
       <div class="dashboard__dropdown-item-text">
            <div class="dashboard__dropdown-name">Text Here</div>
       </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="dashboard__dropdown-item">
       <div class="dashboard__dropdown-item-text">
            <div class="dashboard__dropdown-name">Text Here</div>
       </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="dashboard__dropdown-item">
       <div class="dashboard__dropdown-item-text">
            <div class="dashboard__dropdown-name">Text Here</div>
       </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="dashboard__dropdown-item">
       <div class="dashboard__dropdown-item-text">
            <div class="dashboard__dropdown-name">Text Here</div>
       </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="dashboard__dropdown-item">
       <div class="dashboard__dropdown-item-text">
            <div class="dashboard__dropdown-name">Text Here</div>
       </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="dashboard__dropdown-item">
       <div class="dashboard__dropdown-item-text">
            <div class="dashboard__dropdown-name">Text Here</div>
       </div>
    </a>

    <div class="dashboard__dropdown-more">
         <div class="dashboard__dropdown-container">
         <!--  -->
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас функция `firstThreeOnly` вторую строку не обрабатывает, т.к. на первой строке вы возвращаете значение `return ( index > 2 ? 'dashboard__dropdown-item-active' : '' );`
Если я правильно понял, то так будет правильно.

```js
let items = $('.dashboard__dropdown-item');
let container = $('.dashboard__dropdown-container')
//если класс "dashboard__dropdown-item-active" надо всем элементам добавлять, то переместите его до условия.
items.each((index, item) => {
    (index > 2) && $(item).addClass('dashboard__dropdown-item-active').appendTo(container);
})
```

```css
.dashboard__dropdown-container {
background-color: lightGreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard__items-content">
    <a href="#" class="dashboard__dropdown-item">
        <div class="dashboard__dropdown-item-text">
            <div class="dashboard__dropdown-name">Text Here</div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="dashboard__dropdown-item">
        <div class="dashboard__dropdown-item-text">
            <div class="dashboard__dropdown-name">Text Here</div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="dashboard__dropdown-item">
        <div class="dashboard__dropdown-item-text">
            <div class="dashboard__dropdown-name">Text Here</div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="dashboard__dropdown-item">
        <div class="dashboard__dropdown-item-text">
            <div class="dashboard__dropdown-name">Text Here</div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="dashboard__dropdown-item">
        <div class="dashboard__dropdown-item-text">
            <div class="dashboard__dropdown-name">Text Here</div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="dashboard__dropdown-item">
        <div class="dashboard__dropdown-item-text">
            <div class="dashboard__dropdown-name">Text Here</div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="dashboard__dropdown-more">
        <div class="dashboard__dropdown-container">
            <!--  -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да это работает, а как сделать чтобы на ширине до 1280px оставалось 3 элемента, на ширине 767 - 1280 оставалось 2 элемента, а затем элементы не перекидывались в родителя dashboard__dropdown-container вовсе?

Comment: @DaniilLav смотрите в сторону window.matchMedia

Comment: Так и пробую решить, спасибо Вам за помощь!